# Nameko RPC Authentication Scheme

Tags: python-3.7, nameko

I am trying to identify whethere there are any authentication patterns for Nameko when using the RPC calls. For HTTP they're are some well documented examples with JWT, but with RPC this is lacking.

What I want to achieve is that service to service communication is secured and authenticated and that if the service processes a message, that that message also has identifiers that can be authenticated (e.g. user objects).

Is there any "pattern" for this or would this require me to implement this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a toy example here: https://gist.github.com/mattbennett/8a67956ea78d4481d5ea9072e770ba4b

It's basically the same as the JWT examples you've probably found -- put the authentication token in the `context_data` and then enforce auth a DependencyProvider that reads it.